# PowerShell join/link variables data with foreach

Tags: powershell

```
$list = "data1", "data2"
$joinedlinks = "link1", "link2"
$list1 = foreach ($listed in $list) {
foreach ($joined in $joinedlinks) {
$listed + " - " + $joined
}
}
$list1
```

Output:

```
data1 - link1
data1 - link2
data2 - link1
data2 - link2
```

How do I get output to look like this? So Data1 equals Link1? Since right now it equals 1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2.

```
data1 - link1
data2 - link2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop so you can index into both arrays at the same position each time:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $list.Count; $i++){
    $list[$i] + ' - ' + $joinedlinks[$i]
}
```